# Move cursor on middle button paste in Sublime Text 3

Tags: linux, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

<sub>(Note: this question is different from [Middle button paste deleted text in Sublime 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31251817/middle-button-paste-deleted-text-in-sublime-3?noredirect=1#comment50510339_31251817) )</sub>

I'm using Sublime Text 3 on Linux (but it also applies to Sublime Text 2).

As expected, when I middle mouse button click, it copy-pastes the previously highlighted text. Unfortunately, it doesn't move the cursor to the end of the pasted text, which is the default behavior in all other apps I know (instead, it doesn't move the cursor at all).

Does anyone know how to change this behavior (do not move cursor on middle-button paste) to the expected one (move cursor to end of pasted text)?

Comment: I'm using Linux Mint and when I use middle click to paste, the cursor doesn't moves, so the text I am copying is still selected and the cursor is still in the selected text, is that what you are describing? I also get this behaviour using gedit but not in firefox while writting in this box.  You can see in mousemap that the command being called is paste_selection_clipboard, you can replace this for your own plugin to make it move cursor to end of pasted text. Is this solution valid for you? I can try to implement it but maybe a external program would be needed to simulate a click.

Comment: @sergioFC Thx! Yes this is what I am describing, and indeed gedit does the same as Sublime, but Chrome, Firefox, and emacs do the behaviour I prefer. Any solution is fine for me, but I don't know (yet) how to write a plugin for Sublime, so I was wondering if somebody had a quick fix, or came accross the same problem and already solved it.

Comment: @sergioFC I found a fix, in case you're interested ;-)

Comment: Awesome, now I am under windows, but I will use it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just found a fix, it's actually super easy.

Just create a file named `Default (Linux).sublime-mousemap` with the following content:

```
[
    {
        "button": "button3",
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "command": "paste_selection_clipboard"
    }
]
```

And save it in your Packages/User/ folder (in my case: /home/boris/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/). That's it.

Explanation: the default mousemap does not have the line `"press_command": "drag_select"`, which is the one telling Sublime to change the cursor position on click.