# Middle button paste deleted text in Sublime 3

Tags: linux, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

<sub>(Note: This question is different from [Move cursor on middle button paste in Sublime Text 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31251691/move-cursor-on-middle-button-paste-in-sublime-text-3?noredirect=1#comment50510095_31251691) )</sub>

I am using Sublime Text 3 on Linux (but it also applies to Sublime Text 2).

In both emacs and vim, it is possible to highlight some text (this copies it to the clipboard), delete the text, then paste it elsewhere with the middle mouse button. This is my usual workflow to move some text (select->delete->middleclick).

On Sublime however, it doesn't paste anything, i.e., the middle button paste functionality only works with non-deleted text, apparently. Does anyone know how to make it work with deleted text too?

Comment: @JonTrauntvein I have noticed that there are two different questions `Why it doesn't work with deleted text?` and `Why it doesn't the cursor gets moved?` Now stackoverflow doesn't allows me to delete the upvote I gave to your comment :p

Comment: I've found that ussing parcellite solves this problem in gedit, but not in sublime text. See [Clipboard persistence](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ClipboardPersistence) for more info.

Comment: @sergioFC Thx for the lead! This is interesting, too bad it doesn't work for Sublime.

Comment: I think you need to file a feature request to sublime text , as this is internally handled by the application supplying the selection content. You could use `autocutsel` or similar to synchronize the buffers, but after deleting you'd still have to use `Ctrl+v` for paste. So it would probably be easier to use `Ctrl+x` for cutting either.

Comment: @DominikGebhart thx for the suggestion, I just did it: http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/822073-/

Comment: According to [this](https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=5848&start=0) the problem was solved in Nightly Build 2184. They say `Primary selection isn't cleared when the selection is cleared`. Maybe they finally don't added that changes to the next version of sublime.

Comment: @sergioFC I guess that "clearing the selection" just means "deselecting what was selected" (e.g., by clicking somewhere else). That would be different than "deleting the selection" as I imply in my question, meaning "deleting the text that was selected". Probably Sublime keeps in memory what was selected before clearing, but if you delete it you don't have access anymore to the content. That's just pure speculation though.

Comment: I guess you're right. I am not an English native speaker but I though tha clearing was the same as deleting. For me if you select a word and then only delete some of the last charactets you could still paste the first part of the word that has not been deleted yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've came with plugin like this:

```python
import sublime, sublime_plugin
import re

class MyListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
  def __init__(self):
    sublime_plugin.EventListener.__init__(self)
    self.deleted = '' 
    self.mark_for_clear = ''
    self.clipboard_save = ''
    self.empty_matcher = re.compile('^\s+$')

  # Clear last deleted word if user made highlight of another one
  # Delete if you want to e.g delete one word and highlight another to replace
  def on_selection_modified(self, view):
    selected_text = view.substr(view.sel()[0])
    if self.mark_for_clear != '' and self.mark_for_clear != self.deleted:
      self.deleted = ''
      self.mark_for_clear = ''
    if len(selected_text) > 0 and not self.empty_matcher.match(selected_text):
      self.mark_for_clear = selected_text

  def on_text_command(self, view, name, args):
    # Save deleted word if command was deletion command
    if name in ['right_delete', 'left_delete']:
      self.deleted = view.substr(view.sel()[0])
      #print("Deleted: %s " % self.deleted)
    # Propagate saved deleted word to clipboard and change command to
    # standard paste (we can only control standard paste clipboard)
    if name == "paste_selection_clipboard" and len(self.deleted) > 0:
      #print("Pasting:%s" % self.deleted)
      self.clipboard_save = sublime.get_clipboard()
      sublime.set_clipboard(self.deleted)
      # Comment line below to enable multiple middle-click pasting of deleted words:
      self.deleted = ''  
      return("paste", 'HackedByAlkuzad')

  # If we are after paste_selection_clipboard command, return old clipboard
  def on_post_text_command(self, view, name, args):
    if name == 'paste' and len(self.clipboard_save) > 0 and args == 'HackedByAlkuzad':
      sublime.set_clipboard(self.clipboard_save)
      self.clipboard_save = ''
```

This plugin will detect delete comamnd (right = delete, left = backspace) and copy deleted content to memory. Then if user uses middle-click paste it replaces clipboard with deleted content and pastes it. After paste it restores saved clipboard.

I assumed that the copy from deletion should work on empty space (ST does not have insert mode without Vintage). To change that behaviour you can delete on_selection_modified function to stop checking for that explictly, however highlighting the new word will not copy it to middle-button clipboard.

Edit:
Version for system-wide clipboard using Linux xclip (taken from pyperclip)

```python
import sublime, sublime_plugin
import re
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, check_call, CalledProcessError

class DeletedToClipboard(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
  empty_matcher = re.compile('^\s*$')

  def __init__(self):
    sublime_plugin.EventListener.__init__(self)
    try:
      check_call(['which','xclip'])
    except CalledProcessError:
      sublime.error_message("You have to have xclip installed to use DeletedToClipboard")

  @classmethod
  def _is_empty(cls, text):
    return len(text) <= 0 or cls.empty_matcher.match(text) 
        # Thanks pyperclip :)
  @classmethod
  def _copy_to_system_clipboard(cls, text):
    # try secondary if not working
    p = Popen(['xclip', '-selection', 'primary'], stdin=PIPE)
    try:
        p.communicate(input=bytes(text, 'utf-8'))
    except Exception as e:
      print("Error on paste to clipboard, is xclip installed ? \n{}".format(e))

  def on_text_command(self, view, name, args):
    # Save deleted word if command was deletion command and selected text was not empty
     if name in ['right_delete', 'left_delete']:
      deleted = []
      for region in view.sel():
        text = view.substr(region)
        if not DeletedToClipboard._is_empty(text):
          deleted.append(text)
      if deleted != []:
        self._copy_to_system_clipboard("\n".join(deleted))
```

Comment: I haven't tested it extensively but I like it. It would be better if there was a solution related to Linux clipboard management but it seems it doesn't exists, so a plugin is a nice solution. You can add a condition so it only saves deleted text if selection length is > 0 E.g.: select a word, delete it while it is selected, then I press backspace multiple times deleting previous characters (without selecting them), then nothing is copied as an empty string was saved when I deleted characters without selecting them. Good work, you deserve your bounty.

Comment: Copy only if len > 0 and using linux xclip added :)

Comment: I had forgotten to upvote :p What is the diference of this new version that uses xclip?

Comment: @sergioFC It will use standard Xorg clipboard so you e.g copy text from deletion to another program. Previous one will work only inside sublime. It's also cleaner and less hacky ;)

Comment: @alkuzad Thx, this seems great!! I'll try this on Monday when I have more time.

Comment: Sorry, I realize I still didn't accept your answer. Works like a charm, I'm using the first method (xclip not installed by default in Kubuntu).